# JavaCV transpose FFmpegFrameFilter is not working properly

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-capture, javacv, android-ffmpeg

I am able to rotate video but facing issue in rotating as per [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose).

I tried to hardcode filter as following.

```
FFmpegFrameFilter frameFilter = new FFmpegFrameFilter("transpose=cclock", 
previewWidth, previewHeight);
```

According to documentation, `transpose=cclock` filter should rotate video counter clockwise 90degree. but it is rotating video for 180 degree.

I also tried to use `transpose=0/1/2/3`

- 0 = 90CounterCLockwise and Vertical Flip (default) (this does nothing)
- 1 = 90Clockwise (even this is also does nothing)
- 2 = 90CounterClockwise (this is rotating video at 180 degree)
- 3 = 90Clockwise and Vertical Flip (this behaves same as value2 : 120 degree rotation)

**For example**

`FFmpegFrameFilter frameFilter = new FFmpegFrameFilter("transpose=2", 
 previewWidth, previewHeight);`

[This accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33447014/4647628) is also not working.

In short All i want, is rotate video 90 degree counter clockwise. which I am not able to achieve.

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/CrazyOrr/FFmpegRecorder/issues/37)

Library used for JavaCV : https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv